# Android app crashes while assigning that onClickListener

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener

I want to assign an `OnClickListener` for some dynamically declared elements which exist in a dynamically declared `LinearLayout`, I'm using `getChildAt()` within my `OnClickListener` in order to deal with the elements which exist in the `LinearLayout` but when doing that my app crashes and when I tried to remove `myChildAt()` and just let it deals with the `LinearLayout` directly it worked fine, this is my code:

```
    List<LinearLayout> inner_ver = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){
        LinearLayout temp_inner_ver = new LinearLayout(this);
        temp_inner_ver.setLayoutParams(temp_lay);
        temp_inner_ver.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        temp_inner_ver.setWeightSum(2);
        temp_inner_ver.setPadding(7, 7, 7, 7);
        inner_ver.add(temp_inner_ver);
        }

for(int j = 0 ; j < inner_ver.size() ; j++){
    // the LinearLayout declaration
    inner_ver.get(j).addView(icon1);
    icon1.setLayoutParams(lp_icon);
    icon1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ac_overlay);
    icon1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    icon1.setTag(NORMAL);

    // the elements declaration
    TextView text1 = new TextView(this);
    icon1.addView(text1);
    text1.setLayoutParams(text_name);
    text1.setText("something");
    text1.setTextSize(12);
    text1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    ImageButton image = new ImageButton(this);
    icon1.addView(image);
    image.setLayoutParams(lp_ineer_ver);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.grpbuttonfocus6);
    image.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    Button testbut = new Button(this);
    icon1.addView(testbut);
    testbut.setLayoutParams(lp_ineer_ver);
    testbut.setText(" 8");
    testbut.setTextSize(12);
    testbut.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    testbut.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    ImageButton testcol = new ImageButton(this);
    icon1.addView(testcol);
    testcol.setLayoutParams(lp_ineer_ver);
    testcol.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_cool);
    testcol.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    TextView text2 = new TextView(this);
    icon1.addView(text2);
    text2.setLayoutParams(lp_ineer_ver);
    text2.setText("00");
    text2.setTextSize(12);

    assignListener(icon1);

}

public void assignListener(final LinearLayout l) {

 l.getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    l.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_grpbuttonfocus10);// this Line Getting a NullPointerException
                }
            });
        }
```

and when making it like the following, it works fine:

```
public void assignListener(final LinearLayout l) {
     l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_grpbuttonfocus10); 
                    }
                });
            }
```

**The LogCat View:**
(it gives me a `NullPointerException` on the line shown above in the code)

```
01-14 12:22:06.308: INFO/ActivityManager(93): START {flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.example.solaceap/.HomeView (has extras)} from pid 602
01-14 12:22:06.308: WARN/WindowManager(93): Failure taking screenshot for (222x135) to layer 21015
01-14 12:22:06.625: DEBUG/dalvikvm(602): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 3% free 11649K/11975K, paused 86ms
01-14 12:22:06.995: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(602): Shutting down VM
01-14 12:22:06.995: WARN/dalvikvm(602): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.solaceap/com.example.solaceap.HomeView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at com.example.solaceap.HomeView.assignListener(HomeView.java:669)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at com.example.solaceap.HomeView.setRooms(HomeView.java:518)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at com.example.solaceap.HomeView.setAllRooms(HomeView.java:359)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at com.example.solaceap.HomeView.declare_dynamics(HomeView.java:307)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at com.example.solaceap.HomeView.declare(HomeView.java:62)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at com.example.solaceap.HomeView.onCreate(HomeView.java:45)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
01-14 12:22:07.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(602):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: "Android app crashes" hints that you should run `adb logcat` and post the relevant parts of the stacktrace here.

Comment: Where is the code , that you attach the ,LinearLayout to ParentView

Comment: `adb logcat` including the "caused by", if any

Comment: @keyboardsurfer well, look at the updates

Comment: @18446744073709551615 have a look at the updates

Comment: @Arju that parent(ver_rooms) is hardcoded in the xml file

Comment: where is `icon1` defined ?

Comment: @Arju it's just a `new LinearLayout`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to set the listener directly to the view instead of going over the parent.

I am not sure if I get the right view but you should call `assignListener(image);` (which should be child 1 from the icon1 layout).

Than just use the second version of your `assignListener()` you have posted:

```
public void assignListener(final ImageView imageView) { // changed type
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_grpbuttonfocus10); 
        }
    });
}
```